# How to get click event handler names of ToolStripDropDownItem?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a old project in `Windows Forms` which has more than 300 menus with menu click events throughout the MDI form.
Is there any way to get the click event names in strings (e.g. "toolStripMenuItem_Click")?
I tried like this,

```
foreach (ToolStripMenuItem menu in menuStrip.Items)
{
   foreach (ToolStripDropDownItem submenu in menu.DropDownItems)
   {
       var _events= submenu.GetType()
                     .GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                     .OrderBy(pi => pi.Name).ToList();
   }
}
```

But it always returns empty. What is correct way to achieve this?

Comment: In case you need the names at runtime: Do your event handlers follow the convention that their names begin with the name of the menu item itself?

Comment: **Why** do you want this information? What problem are you trying to solve? (and reflecting the _type_ of `ToolStripDropDownItem` is not going to tell you anything about the contents your own project)

Comment: @NineBerry Some menu's has different handlers. Rest follows the convention.

Comment: @Dai I am goint to generate menu's dynamically according to user rights. Since all menu click handlers has lots of conditions( like whether, which, how) to open forms and all are working perfectly, I will just map the Event Handler Names with the corresponding Menu Names to trigger menu click. But there is a lots of menus and event handlers are in the mdiparent with functions and all. It's nasty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieving event handlers at runtime is not easy especially within the Forms framework where some events have special handling in the background.

A simpler approach (if you don't need the names at runtime but at design time) is to use regular expressions on your `MyForm.designer.cs` file to extract the names of the click handlers.

See this sample source:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fileLocaton = @"C:\Users\nineb\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp37\WindowsFormsApp37\Form1.Designer.cs";
    string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(fileLocaton);

    // Find all menu items in the designer file
    var matches = Regex.Matches(fileContent, @"System\.Windows\.Forms\.ToolStripMenuItem (.+?)\;");
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        string menuName = match.Groups[1].Value;
        textBox1.AppendText("Menuitem " + menuName + Environment.NewLine);

        // For each menu item, find all the event handlers
        var clickMatches = Regex.Matches(fileContent, 
            @"this\." + Regex.Escape(menuName) + @"\.Click \+\= new System\.EventHandler\(this\.(.+?)\)\;");
        foreach (Match clickMatch in clickMatches)
        {
            string handlerName = clickMatch.Groups[1].Value;
            textBox1.AppendText("Eventhandler " + handlerName + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is amazing. It's what I needed. You just saved me a day!